При использовании selenium забивается полностью диск dev/sda1
На облачном сервере расположен парсер, который каждый день проходит по нужным ссылкам и собирает нужные данные. Selenium используется только для сайта investing.com, и для него есть около 80 ссылок.
Оперативки на сервере 4 ГБ. Диск 20 ГБ. Стала замечать, что парсер периодически отрабатывает с ошибкой, как раз когда диск dev/sda1 занят полностью
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed

Помогает только перезагрузка сервера.
Может есть еще какие-то варианты, как почистить диск, или как настроить selenium, чтоб он потреблял меньше памяти?
Сейчас для него такие настройки
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/127.0.6533.88 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")
options.add_argument("--disable-images")
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

Вот вывод команды df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           389M  1.0M  388M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G   20G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           389M   16K  389M   1% /run/user/0


Как-то вы неоднозначно выражаетесь, у вас и ОЗУ 20Гб и ПЗУ 20Гб, так вы не знаете как диск очистить  или чтобы selenium меньше ОЗУ потреблял?


driver.quit() после парсинга 2) --disk-cache-dir=/путь/ положить временные файлы в отдельную папку, чистить после парсинга. ‍♀️


@Oopss, поправила вопрос. Мне нужно и то, и другое. Я мало работала с файловой системой, и не понимаю, куда какие файлы сохраняются. мне кажется, что что-то просто забивается лишними файлами, и поэтому selenium не отрабатывает. ну и так же, пытаюсь понять, как ускорить работу selenium и чтоб он меньше ресурсов потреблял

@Amgarak, driver.quit() использую после сбора данных с каждой ссылки. или это избыточно? про  --disk-cache-dir=/путь/ посмотрю, спасибо!

Это всё конечно хорошо, но как минимум сперва найдите что конкретно занимает место, вдруг вообще не кэш

@ЕленаСергеева можно поэкспериментировать, например: driver.close() - закрывает активное окно браузера.
driver.quit() — закрывает все окна браузера и завершает сеанс/процесс драйвера. Но в любом случае завершать работу браузера надо, в противном случае будут открываться всё новые и новые экземпляры, что по итогу и сожрёт память.

"...На облачном сервере...", "...Оперативки на сервере 4 ГБ. Диск 20 ГБ..." - это о сервере или о телефоне, причём кнопочном?

@FoxFox что выдали, на том и работаю. до этого ни разу не пользовалась серверами, поэтому и не знала, какая конфигурация нужна

@Елена Сергеева вы разделите вопросы отдельно про память, отдельно про диск, это вообще разные подходы, про диск могу предложить, если весь объем занимает результат вашего парсинга, делите файл на порции и скачивайте себе на локальный сервер.

Для поиска, что занимает: du -s ..., а может даже что-то типа find / | sort > tmp0, diff tmp0 tmp1

В питоне есть tempfile.TemporaryDirectory. На сервере наверняка есть cron
